# non-UB constexpr function to bitshift a float or double?

Tags: c++, c++14, bitwise-operators, type-punning

I want a constexpr function (without UB) to calculate a checksum of a message. According to the specification

> The Checksum is computed by running an exclusive OR of the 16-bit words of the message from
> header field MSG_TYPE (inclusive) up to the last field of the message body

I've figured out, that I can't `reinterpret_cast` the message body as an array of `uint16_t`, as it yields UB. But I cannot use `std::copy` inside a constexpr function, so for one message I had a working and valid approach that used bitshifting.

```
/*!
     * \brief LRF MESSAGE
     */
    struct LrfMes
    {
        //<! Message ID
        constexpr static MessageID message_id = MessageID::lrf;
        constexpr static MessageType message_type = MessageType::commandRequiringAResponse;
        constexpr static uint32_t message_length = 16;

        constexpr uint16_t calc_checksum() const
        {
            const uint16_t body[]{
                    uint16_t(uint16_t((uint8_t)lrfFire) << 8 | (uint8_t)setEcho),
                    uint16_t (uint16_t((uint8_t)setRange) << 8 | (uint8_t)setFreq),
                    uint16_t(lrfRangeMax >> 16),
                    uint16_t (lrfRangeMin),
                    uint16_t (lrfRangeMax >> 16),
                    uint16_t (lrfRangeMax)
            };
            uint16_t res = 0;

            for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(LrfMes) / 2; ++i)
                res ^= body[i];

            return res;
        }

        LrfFire lrfFire;
        LrfSetEcho setEcho;
        LrfSetRange setRange;
        LrfSetFreq setFreq;
        uint32_t lrfRangeMin;
        uint32_t lrfRangeMax;
    };
```

Apart from being available only since 14 standard (ideally it must be implemented in 11), I have to write such method for each and every structure I have.

But I have faced a problem when I have floats as struct members.

```
struct LosSteeringMsg
    {
        //<! Message ID
        constexpr static MessageID message_id = MessageID::losSteering;
        constexpr static MessageType message_type = MessageType::commandWithoutResponse;
        constexpr static uint32_t message_length = 32;

        constexpr uint16_t calc_checksum() const
        {
            
//            const uint16_t body[]{
//                uint16_t (uint16_t((uint8_t)steeringScr << 8) | (uint8_t)steeringMode),
//                uint16_t (uint16_t((uint8_t)resetOffset << 8) | (uint8_t)pauseScan),
//                uint16_t (reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(azmSteering) >> 16) // this does not work
//
//            }

            uint16_t res = 0;

            return res;
        }

        LosStSCR steeringScr;
        LosStMode steeringMode;
        LosStResetOffset resetOffset;
        LosStPauseScanMes pauseScan;
        float azmSteering;
        float elevSteering;
        float azmAngle;
        float elevAngle;
        float azmSpeed;
        float elevSpeed;
    };
```

So, what are my options?

- Should I just give up on defining these methods as constexpr? This would actually simplify my life, giving me an ability to write only one function that uses `std::copy`.
- Use `uint32_t` to store float values. Though it will allow me to calculate a checksum at compile time (for testing, for example), it wouldn't make much difference since I'll need to initialize integers from floats.
- Any other option??

Comment: Why do you want `calc_checksum` to be `constexpr`? Do you have a `constexpr LosSteeringMsg` variable somewhere, with values of all data members known at compile time, that you want to be able to compute the checksum for at compile time?

Comment: *"constexpr function (without UB)"*. Compilers have to diagnose UB in contant contexts. :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 I know. I mentioned that because in other answers there are many suggestions to use unions or type punning...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik if you are asking just out of curiosity, yes. I have. I have all the possible compile time tests involving these structs and their traits and values.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this is just your opinion. And I didn't ask for one about should I do it at compile time or not. I have messages that may I create to send. And I'd rather catch an invalid checksum at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

In C++20, you can do this:

```
std::bit_cast<std::uint32_t>(azmSteering) >> 16;
```

Prior to C++20 there is no simple solution that works in a constexpr function. This has no UB, but is regardless not allowed in constexpr function:

```
std::uint32_t u32;
std::memcpy(&u32, &azmSteering, sizeof azmSteering);
u32 >> 16;
```

> Should I just give up on defining these methods as constexpr?

Prior to C++20: Maybe. Technically it may be possible to extract the correct bits using floating point operations but it would be quite convoluted.

Comment: Well, I am aware of beautiful C++20 features like that, but there is no way I could jump  higher than 14. As I said already, copying into memory would ease the whole checksum thing for every structure at once. But I'd use it only in case there's no way to use constexpr. If you state that it is technically impossible to do, I will mark your answer. Because I would like to know exactly if it IS possible.